# Image not appearing in github pages

Tags: image, github, github-pages

I have an image in img folder. This image is not visible on the website but later it appears through some event in javascript. The problem is when the website is live I checked the Sources from devloper tools and in the img folder the image is not availabe, although the image is availabe in the git repo.
How can I make the git hub pages to load the image in the folder even if it not being used in the website from the beginning. The image is just availabe in repo but dose not load in the live website.